# Is this IP configuration valid?

Tags: ipv4

We have to install some network devices (ip camera, max=30) at one of our client sites, so we asked them to give us an IP range.

The client sends the following details,

IP range:= 192.168.0.264/296
Subnet  := 255.255.254.0
Gateway := 192.168.0.1

Is this valid? If yes, any details about this will be very helpful?

After some Googling and head scratching, i came to the following conclusion,
IP range := 192.168.1.8  to 192.168.1.40

Is this correct?

Comment: 192.168.0.264/296 is not a valid range. Maybe you mean 192.168.0.0/23? I think they mean 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.42, but that is a very weird way to write that...

Comment: This is so wrong in different levels! Period.

Comment: That is a very odd way of notating a /23 network, but I suppose it does have the benefit of separating the network bits from the host bits. If only there was a standard (RFC 791) way that the client could have written the address range.... :-)

Comment: @Cown: My bad i included x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.255 in my calculations :-(

Comment: @user82037 yes i did sorry

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> IP range:= 192.168.0.264/296

This is nonsense. The dots are in between octets/bytes and 8 bit can only be 2^8-1=255 max.

With

> Subnet := 255.255.254.0
>
> Gateway := 192.168.0.1

the IP range of 192.168.0.0/23 is 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.254.

Comment: I know that's not the correct way, but i was considering ip address as <network-id>+<host-id>. By the way we have asked the client to clarify.

Comment: "ip address as <network-id>+<host-id>" - in principle correct, but you need to add the carry to the next more significant octet. Fortunately, IPv6 uses hexadecimal...